# Camouflaged chat app for Android (does not look like a chat app)

Tags: android, chat, privacy

I have a scenario where a client needs to have an app to chat with someone without anyone else being able to know, cursorily, that an app is a communication app or has the ability to provide communication (text chat primarily).

A desirable example scenario would be a "game" (any kind of app really) that, when opened, there is a function somewhere that leads the user into a chat application where the user will be able to innocuously talk to someone else and then easily switch back over to the app's other functionality and then quit without prying eyes being able to EASILY get into the chat functionality.  The chat should also have no history or be easily clearable.

Do any such apps exist?

Comment: Is it OK if you need to perform a particular action to see whether new messages have come? Or do you want to be sort of "notified" when there is a new message?

Comment: If you need compatibility with a particular protocol (for instance Facebook Messenger) then please edit your question to add it as a requirement. Also, with how many people do you want to chat? Just one other person? Or hundreds or persons? They will have to use the same camouflaged app, right?

Comment: No particular protocol - just two devices with the same app is fine. One person is alright, but a few would be better. Yes, they all would use the same camouflaged app.

Comment: Would you accept a solution that allows you to "hide" an app, from a casual examination of your 'phone? Couple that with a "Boss Key" app & it would be easier to get an answer. If anyone looks over your should while chatting, it doesn't matter what app you are using.

Comment: @Mawg I'd rather not as it takes a little longer for switching away and when someone is in an abuse situation and a paranoid abuser comes into the scene, it takes a little longer to hide the evidence and switch away. Switch time and reduction of evidence is critical when one is in a panic state.